# Regex for country code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for country code, which should limit to four characters maximum, only symbol allowed is a + sign. When the + is used, the + has to be in the beginning, and it should have at least one number.

Valid cases

```
+1
1
+12
12
+123
1234
```

Invalid cases

```
+
+1234
12345
1+
12+
<empty>
etc.
```

The expression that I have right now.

```
/(\+\d{1,3})/
```

Can it be more elegant?

-Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work. I used

```
/^(\+?\d{1,3}|\d{1,4})$/
```

[See results](https://regex101.com/r/dR5ngE/1)

Edit:

The //gm flags are *global* and *multiline*, respectively. You need those if you have a string that can have multiple places to match a country code, or there are multiple lines in your string. If your string is going to be more than just a possible country code, you'd need to get rid of the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the regex. To use the regex, you'd want something like this:

```
var regex = /^(\+?\d{1,3}|\d{1,4})$/gm
var str = "+123"
var match = str.match(regex);
//match is an array, with one result in this case. So match[0] == "+123"
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what the /gm flag is? How do I accommodate that in my actual code?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati I explained it in my edit. It depends what your strings will look like, but I think I explained it overall pretty well. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for various ways to match once you have a regex expression.

Comment: ++++23 passes too. How can be this a valid answer?

Comment: @Mar Are you sure that one passes? I added that example to my regex and it doesn't match. https://regex101.com/r/dR5ngE/22

Answer (score 4):

country codes can be of following types

- +1
- +91
- +223
- +1-224

The javascript regex that makes sure that the input is one if the

```
/^\+(\d{1}\-)?(\d{1,3})$/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a case differentiation. Either with or without leading plus sign:

```
(\+\d{1-3})|(\d{1,4})
```

Whether you want to anchor the expression to line limits (`^` and `$`) or check for leading or trailing white spaces or the like obviously depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I prepared this according to [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), for parsing correct information for 1 or 2 digit country codes this is much more efficient, but needs improvement for subterritories if you need them;

```
(?:\+|00)(1|7|2[07]|3[0123469]|4[013456789]|5[12345678]|6[0123456]|8[1246]|9[0123458]|(?:2[12345689]|3[578]|42|5[09]|6[789]|8[035789]|9[679])\d)
```

Comment: this is good but it can't match +1684 country code for American Samoa or the codes more than 4 digits