# How to validate all country codes using RegExp JS

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to validate all country codes that exist and the variations are as follows:

I've already looked on stack overflow for the answer to this and there is no answer that includes the country codes that have dashes in them.

n

nn

nnn

n-nnn

nn-nnnn

this is what I have so far, but it's obviously wrong and I was hoping someone could help me with it.

```
([\d{1,3} | \d{1}\-\d{3} | \d{2}\-\d{4}])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for country code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511819/regex-for-country-code)

Comment: `/^(\+?\d{1,3}|\d{1,4})$/` this might work i guess as in other SO questions

Comment: This matches all your given examples: `/^(\+?\d{1,3}|\d{1}\-\d{3}|\d{2}\-\d{4})$/`

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for your answer. I would like to give you credit for it if you would like to post it as an answer. I ended up using this instead, but it was inspired from your regex. Thanks :) `/(44\-\d{4}|1\-\d{3}|\d{1,3})/`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
/^\d\d?(\d?|-\d{3,4})$/
```

Comment: This doesn't match anything before the dash